# How do I get cd to switch to the full path when following symbolic links?

Tags: shell, symbolic-link

How can I get the shell to understand the full path after following a symbolic link. In the example below I'd like the first "pwd" command to report "/Users/sholden/Projects/PS1/examples", and the "cd .." command to take me to /Users/sholden/Projects/PS1/ rather than back to my home directory. I have a dim memory of a setting that did this in the Bourne shell (or was it Korn?*) but I'm having trouble dredging up the details from 25 years ago ...

```
AirHead:~ sholden$ ls -ld examples
lrwxr-xr-x  1 sholden  staff  53 Nov 15 09:33 examples -> /Users/sholden/Projects/PS1/examples
AirHead:~ sholden$ cd examples
AirHead:examples sholden$ pwd
/Users/sholden/examples
AirHead:examples sholden$ cd ..
AirHead:~ sholden$ pwd
/Users/sholden
AirHead:~ sholden$
```

Was it "set hardpaths?" Thanks in advance.

* It was neither - I was a `csh` user back then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should use `cd` with `-P` option to do that.

from man pange:

```
 -P     Handle the operand dot-dot physically; symbolic link components shall be resolved before dot-dot components
              are processed (see step 7. in the DESCRIPTION).
```

small test to show how does it work:

```
kent@ArchT60:/tmp$ ls -ld /opt/google/picasa/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  5  2010 /opt/google/picasa/

kent@ArchT60:/tmp$ ln -s /opt/google/picasa/ cdLink
kent@ArchT60:/tmp$ ls -l cdLink
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kent kent 19 Nov 15 21:23 cdLink -> /opt/google/picasa/

kent@ArchT60:/tmp$ cd -P cdLink
kent@ArchT60:/opt/google/picasa$ pwd
/opt/google/picasa

kent@ArchT60:/opt/google/picasa$ cd /tmp/cdLink
kent@ArchT60:/tmp/cdLink$ 
kent@ArchT60:/tmp/cdLink$ cd -P ..
kent@ArchT60:/opt/google$
```

i think the example above showed what you are looking for.

Comment: +1; fantastic, this is exactly what I tried to find before.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I needed. Thanks a lot for bringing me up to date. I now realie it was the C shell that had that unusual feature.

Comment: this looks promising but doesn't appear to handle nested symlinks, ie `cd -P sym1/sym2` => `sym1/link/`

Answer (score 2):

I have never found a way to do it with symlinks, but if your goal is to quickly change between directories in shell, I wrote a [blog post recently on several alternatives to accomplish exactly that](http://sampsonchen.com/2012/09/18/three-shortcuts-to-quickly-change-directories-in-linux/).

The short answer is to use alias to add something similar to the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias sf='cd ~/SmileForward/smileforward-backend/sfsite/smileforward'
```

Or export all the frequently used directories as variables into your `~/.bashrc`, and just invoke directly with `cd $dir_1` etc:

```
export dir_1='~/some_long_path_name/more_path_names1`
export dir_2='~/some_long_path_name/more_path_names2`
```

There's also [a tool for switching directories based on frequency / recency](https://github.com/rupa/z) called z that I never explored fully.

Comment: alias or variable works for certain link->directorie(s). but not for all link->directories.

Comment: @Kent ah; what I was suggesting was to do it w/o symlinks period.

Comment: in practical I have some variables like your dir_1, dir_2 as well (or put them in cdpath). But not for OP's purpose, just for going to some directory quickly and easily.